# Is it possible to use packages changepage and hanging together?

Tags: packages

I'm trying to change the margins around some paragraphs with hanging indents, but LaTeX throws an error and doesn't really explain what's wrong.  I'm a LaTeX newbie, so please forgive me if I'm making a simple mistake.  Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{changepage}

%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{16pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{.25in}{0in}
\begin{hangparas}{.25in}{1}

    \setlength{\parindent}{0in}

    \textbf{One.}
    \hspace{6pt}
    Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.
    Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.
    Some text.

    \textbf{Two.}
    \hspace{6pt}
    Some more text.  Some more text.  Some more text.  Some more text.  Some
    more text.  Some more text.  Some more text.  Some more text.  Some more
    text.  Some more text.  Some more text.

\end{hangparas}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}


This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, fa
rsi, arabic, monogreek, greek, ibycus, ancientgreek, loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/fullpage.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hanging/hanging.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/changepage/changepage.sty) (./test.aux
)

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.30 \end{adjustwidth}

?
```

Comment: No, you can't: `adjustwidth` uses a list environment, which sets `\parshape`, which takes over the parameters used by `hanging`. What precisely do you want to get?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I just want paragraphs with hanging indents to have different left margins, moved into the page some.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Related question: How could I have found out myself that these two packages are incompatible?

Answer (score 4):

You need neither `adjustwidth` nor `hangparas`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{outpar}
 {\par\setlength{\parindent}{-0.25in}}
 {\par}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{outpar}
\textbf{One.}\quad
  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.
  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.  Some text.
  Some text.

\textbf{Two.}\quad
  Some more text.  Some more text.  Some more text.  Some more text.  Some
  more text.  Some more text.  Some more text.  Some more text.  Some more
  text.  Some more text.  Some more text.
\end{outpar}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed the setting of `\parskip` because I consider it against good typography. In any case, 16pt is too much for any respectable document. `;-)`